# AlarmManager inconsistency

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm using an `AlarmManager` to send a broadcast while the screen is off. This works fine on most devices, but on some (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S4), it takes 30, 40, or even 120 seconds instead of the specified 20s until the broadcast is received. I don't have access to the devices on which this is happening so I can't check the logcat.

This is how I'm setting up the `AlarmManager`:

```
AlarmManager mAlarmManager=(AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
long mInterval = 20 * 1000;
Intent i = new  Intent();
i.setAction(MY_ACTION);
mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + mInterval, mPendingIntent);
```

And this is the receiver, registered in the manifest:

```
private class MyIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyIntentReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(MY_ACTION)) {

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
            wl.acquire();

            Log.e(TAG, "onReceive");

            //Carry out my action...


            wl.release();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Two issues: you should not be spending more than a couple of milliseconds in `onReceive()`, and there already is a `WakeLock` while you are in `onReceive()`. You need your own `WakeLock` if you are passing control to some other component (e.g., `//Carry out my action` is really delegating to an `IntentService`), though then releasing the `WakeLock` where you are is incorrect. If you are delegating to another component, use [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) or the Android Support package's `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I have changed my code over to the WakefulBroadcastReceiver/IntentService-construct, but the inconsistency on the S4 is still there (it works on other devices, as before). If I increase the interval (e.g. 30 or 40 seconds instead of 20), the inconsistency increases exponentially (i.e. it takes 1-2 minutes longer than intended until my action is carried out). I'm stumped by this, because I thought using `RTC_WAKEUP` would ensure that actual time is used rather than only the "device awake"-time?

Comment: It should be. If you can create a reproducible test case, upload it somewhere, and I'll take a peek at it. I have an S4, though it may not be the same S4 model as yours (Samsung applied "S4" to a few devices). Or, try [this `WakefulIntentService` sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful) or [this `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast) and try reproducing your symptoms based on one of those.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, I appreciate it! I'll try your samples and will let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the parameters of the `AlarmManager.set()` method to `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` instead of my initial `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()` based on  [CommonsWare's sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast), and it now works on the S4, too. I don't know why `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` isn't working, as it specifically carries `WAKEUP` in its name and works on all other devices on which I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) changed with the arrival of **API 19**. Many wasted hours on troubleshooting an app that used to work just fine before reading the updated Javadoc.

> **Note**: Beginning with API 19 ([KITKAT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#KITKAT)) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see [`setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setWindow(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and [`setExact(int, long, PendingIntent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). Applications whose `targetSdkVersion` is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.